# Android, loading images efficiently in a list adapter

Tags: android, performance, android-arrayadapter, imagedownload

I am writing an android app.  I have an ArrayAdapter which I am using to display a list of items where part of each item is an image.  I am downloading the images asynchronously in the adapers getView() method and I am using a cache to keep it as efficient as possible and stop too many re-downloads. The problem I am facing is that the getView() method for each item can be called by android as many times as it needs to. It is often called faster than the image can actually download and so the same image can be queued many times for download before it even gets into the cache.  Is there a best practice for how to prevent the images from being queued for download repeatedly?  It just seems like a big waste of mobile data.

Comment: it´s too much to explain here, but this developer guide should help: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The accepted best practice that is recommend by Google for downloading and displaying images in a list or recyclerview is to use the Glide library

https://github.com/bumptech/glide

The api looks like this

`Glide.with(context)
    .load(url)
    .centerCrop()
    .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_spinner)
    .crossFade()
    .into(myImageView);`

Comment: This had some quirks and limitations because I use images with rounded corners but it seems very good thanks.  There was no problem that you cannot get around with a little research

Comment: Yup, Glide is awesome :D

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use third party image downloader library then you can use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)
Its actullay pretty neat and simple to use. It does caching for your app.
You can refer [this](http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/how-to-use-picasso-library-in-android) tutorial.
Happy learning :)